# Is there way you can combine two sheets and yet maintain or preserve the formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a master table sheet and lookup table sheet.

I have a header on both table that has identical columns and some not.

What I want to happen is get everything from the lookup table and combine it to the master sheet that will match the header column.
And once that's done, I want the master table to not lose the formula I created such as:
on column D of master sheet: the formula is:=COUNTIF($C:C,$C2)>1
on column M of master sheet: the formula is: = SUMIF(C:C,C2,K:K)/COUNTIF(C:C,C2)

Hope to hear a solution.

Thank you.

Here is the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dfDEjPYGX4Zx2AVfjbkJo5cDjMwICVbQKMZuGrlZwc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dfDEjPYGX4Zx2AVfjbkJo5cDjMwICVbQKMZuGrlZwc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dfDEjPYGX4Zx2AVfjbkJo5cDjMwICVbQKMZuGrlZwc/edit?usp=sharing